# Default argument for \newcommand

Tags: math-mode, macros

I've create a command to quickly insert derivative operator for my ODE class, but I want to two of the four fields to default to certain values because they will be the most used, but potentially will need to be changed.

```
\newcommand{\dydx}[4]{\frac{d^{#1}{#2}}{d{#3}^{#4}}}
```

I'd like #2 and #3 to be y and x respectively by default but capable of being changed when I need to like `\dxdy{2}{u}{t}{2}`

Comment: I suppose your example is `\dydx`, not `\dxdy`. B.t.w., how can #1 and #4 be different?

Comment: Yes, you're correct on both accounts. Became so used to typing it I didn't even consider they were the same.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind a change in the syntax,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\dydx}{O{y}mO{x}}{%
  \frac
    {d\ifnum#2=1\else^{#2}\fi#1}
    {d#3\ifnum#2=1\else^{#2}\fi}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\dydx{2}+\dydx[u]{2}[t]+\dydx[v]{1}+\dydx{3}[t]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe you'll like the following way, with the same output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dydx}{O{}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { scott/dydx } { #1 }
  \scott_dydx:
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { scott/dydx }
 {
  x .tl_set:N = \l__scott_dydx_x_tl,
  y .tl_set:N = \l__scott_dydx_y_tl,
  n .tl_set:N = \l__scott_dydx_n_tl,
  x .initial:n = x,
  y .initial:n = y,
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \scott_dydx:
 {
  \frac
   {
    d
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l__scott_dydx_n_tl { ^{\l__scott_dydx_n_tl } }
    \l__scott_dydx_y_tl
   }
   {
    d
    \l__scott_dydx_x_tl
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l__scott_dydx_n_tl { ^{\l__scott_dydx_n_tl } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\dydx[n=2]+\dydx[y=u,x=t,n=2]+\dydx[y=v]+\dydx[n=3,x=t]
\]

\end{document}
```